# Raspberry Pi 4 Kiosk Mode - Full Screen Browser minimises after TV Reboot

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

Evening!
Rasp Pi 4
Raspberry Pi OS 64Bit
Latest updates so config.txt is relocated to /boot/firmware/config.txt

Trying to figure out a way i can stop Kiosk mode from coming out of fullscreen browser
Usecase:
Displays a webpage during the day
Team goes home for the night, turns off the TV's
When the TV's boot back up, the Pi now has the address bar and the icons at the top visable
To go back to fullscreen mode, the Pi needs to be rebooted
Code in sudo nano .config/wayfire.ini as below:

```
    [autostart]
    panel = wfrespawn wf-panel-pi
    background = wfrespawn pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
    xdg-autostart = lxsession-xdg-autostart
    chromium = chromium-browser www.url.com --kiosk --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --no-first-run --  ozone-platform=wayland --enable-features=OverlayScrollbar --start-maximized --ignore-certificate- errors
    screensaver = false
    dpms = false
```

I have tried hotswap enable for the HDMI Ports, setting the HDMI Port and its resolution at the display output in wayfire.ini

Tried setting `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` in /boot/firmware/config.txt

Out of ideas!

Thanks!

Googled the hell out of the problem and no beuno

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by switching to Firefox. The following configuration located in `/etc/xdg/autostart/firefox.desktop` works for me. I added 30 s of delay to make sure the service I am accessing is available which you might want to remove (i.e. `Exec=firefox --private-window --kiosk 'http://localhost:8080'`).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Firefox
Comment=Firefox
NoDisplay=false
Exec=sh -c "sleep 30s && firefox --private-window --kiosk 'http://localhost:8080'"
```